# How can I bind a JQuery event to make it only fire once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a help popup that I want to close when somewhere else is clicked. Here's what I have:

```
$('.help[data-info]').click(function(){
  $('.info[a complicated selector]').toggle(400);
  $('*:not(.info[the complicated selector]).one('click','',function(){
    .info[the complicated selector].hide(400);
  });
})
```

But one() isn't what I want before it fires for each element on the page. I only want it to fire once.

Comment: You are missing `'` in the 3rd selector. Also is `''` 2nd param of the `one()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are attaching event handlers to every element in your dom except the help popup?  Hmm...

How about this:

Create a single "mask" div that overlays the entire screen, but is transparent (opacity: 0.0).  Attach the click event handler **only** to that mask div.  Then open up the info div on top of the overlay div.  Clicking anywhere on the page, other than the info div, the event will be captured by the mask div before it gets to anything under it.  In your event handler, hide() the info div, and remove the mask div altogether.  While testing/experimenting with this, start with a partially opaque mask, not fully transparent).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to fire once across all your elements, then you may have to manually unbind all the event handlers when any one is clicked or use a flag:

```
$('.help[data-info]').click(function(){
  $('.info[a complicated selector]').toggle(400);
  var sel = $('*:not(.info[the complicated selector]);
  function hideInfo() {
     .info[the complicated selector].hide(400);
     sel.unbind('click', hideInfo);
  }
  sel.bind('click', hideInfo);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a boolean variable and set it to true after first click, so it doesn't trigger the action again:

```
$('.help[data-info]').click(function() {
  var clicked = false;
  $('.info[a complicated selector]').toggle(400);
  $('*:not(.info[the complicated selector]').one('click','',function() {
    if (!clicked) {
      .info[the complicated selector].hide(400);
       clicked = true;
    }    
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

- You can use the [blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event instead of binding a click event to everything but your popup.
- Add a transparent, full-page `div` between the popup and the rest of the page.  A click event on the transparent `div` could handle the hiding.